# How to remove darkness of a mass of bars in a matlab figure?

Tags: matlab

[image]I made a diagram which includes 500 bars in a matlab figure. The color of bars are blue but due to the large number, some of them are seen compact and black. I used this code for removing the borders of bars:

```
g=bar(...)
g.EdgeColor = 'none';
```

But still the diagram is same whith the dark parts. Can any one help me to make these black bars as blue?

Comment: 500 bars? You might want to consider a different way of displaying your data. I would plot this as a box plot for each action, with an additional line across for the ESEC framework result. That would be much more readable I think.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have done separate analysis as you told. But now, because of some reasons, I am force to make the diagram in above shape.

Comment: Those appear to be multible bar-plots have you set `Edgecolor` for each of them? Have you tried `g.BarWidth = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

`g.EdgeColor = 'none'` works on my computer.

It may be a refreshing problem, did you try :

```
refresh
```

or an alternative

```
g.EdgeAlpha = 0
```

If either of those don't work, please post a [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example), because you may have a problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your both suggestion, but still the diagram is same, black and blue... I think this is not because of the bar borders and has happened due to the mass of diagrams.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example that shows your problem ?